# Swift 4/XCode (macOS): Connect IBOutlet from ViewController.swift to XIB failed

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Thats driving me nuts. I have a project **without** Storyboard. I added a ViewController.swift later "by Hand". Now I want to Connect a NSPopUpButton from the MainMenu.xib as IBOutlet to this ViewController.swift File. But there is no Connection possible. If I try to connect it doesn´t react. I know there is something with Classes where the Controller must be assigned to. But I couldn´t get it right. Perhaps anyone could tell me what to do? On the Picture its the Popup with "Item 1" which should be connected.

http://fs1.directupload.net/images/180719/y5o3g4nj.png

Comment: To be able to connect an UI element to a controller there must be a corresponding **object** of this controller in Interface Builder

Answer (score 0):

To connect UI objects to .xib you need to assign that .xib file class which will be that viewController.swift that you created. For more details you can go to .xib file select it and then select identity inspector for right menu and then write that viewController name. After that you can make IBOutlet. Just for information you visit this url.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPLAz51EP2A
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ViewController class name in the **Class field** of the **Custom Class section** for the MainMenu.xib (Note, the xib object, not the NSPopUpButton object as is in your screenshot.) You'll then be able to connect the IBOutlet.

[image]

Comment: Hm if I click on the xib the Identity Inspector shows nothing. http://fs5.directupload.net/images/180719/hk2clu9n.png